# Term for cousins whose parents were related by marriage?

Tags: kinship-terminology

My father and his brother married two girls who were first cousins to each other.  I know that the children from these marriages are not 'double' cousins, but they are genetically closer than simple first cousins.  Is there a term for this relationship?

Answer (score 4):

Aside from the generic "kin", the overly specific "first cousins through their fathers, second cousins through their mothers" and their consanguinity (15.625%) being slightly higher than for otherwise unrelated first cousins (12.5%), not really; at least not in English. For that matter, not in any other language I know, but there easily might be one which has a specific term for this kind of relationship.

Comment: As a side note, that's the same relationship Albert Einstein had to his second *wife* Elsa Löwenthal née Einstein